# Verifying the distribution of an ensemble of random matrices

Tags: probability-theory, matrices, probability

Suppose one is trying to devise a method to generate random matrices with a certain distribution. How does one verify that the generated matrices follow the desired distribution? In particular, I am interested in uniformly distributed random orthogonal matrices, but I am curious how people test their codes for correctness in general.

Answer (score 1):

In the following [article](http://stuff.mit.edu/people/raj/Acta05rmt.pdf), an experiment is devised to show that the distribution of the largest eigenvalue is given by the Tracy-Widom distribution. See section 10. Perhaps you could modify it.

Comment: I fail to see what part of Section 10 is related to Victor's question and will be grateful if you provide some explanations.